# WebSphere MQ Security Authentication Exception on Unix

Tags: security, unix, authentication, ibm-mq, weblogic9.x

We have our application running on a Sun Solaris system and have a local WebSphere MQ installation. The applcation uses bindings mode to connect to queue manager. When trying to send message to the local queue, the JNDI binding is successfull but we encounter `javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: MQJMS2013: invalid security authentication supplied for MQQueueManager` error. When investigated found that the credentials (userid) used for authentication is not case sensitive as the user on which the application is running. The userid matches but it is not a case sensitive match. By default the user on which the application is running will be passed for authentication, but here the case sensitive match is failing. The application server is WebLogic. Appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In order to open the local queue, the application must have first connected to the queue manager successfully.  The error on the remote queue is a connection error so it is not even getting to the queue manager.  This suggests that you are using different connection factories and that the second one has some differences in the connectivity parameters.  First step is to reconcile those differences.

Also, a MQJMS2013 Security Error can be many things, most of which are not actually MQ issues.  For example some people store their managed objects in LDAP and an authentication problem there will throw this error.  For people who use a filesystem-based JNDI, OS file permissions can cause the same thing.  However if it is an actual WMQ issue (which this appears to be) then the linked exception will contain the MQ Reason Code (for example, MQRC=2035).  If you want to be able to better diagnose MQ (or for that matter any JMS transport) issues, it pays to get in the habit of printing linked exceptions.

If you are not able to resolve this issue based on this input, I would advise updating the question with details of the managed object definitions and the reason code obtained from printing the linked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

We were using createQueueConnection() in QueueConnectionFactory for creating the connection and the issue got resolved by using the method createQueueConnection("",""). The unix userid (webA) is case sensitive and the application was trying to authenticate on the MQ with the case insensitive userid (weba) and MQ queue manager was rejecting the connection attempt. Can you tell us why the application was sending the case insensitive userid (weba) earlier?

Thanks,
Arun